# Get image width and height without downloading in PYTHON

Tags: python

Is there anyway to get image width and height without downloading from original location in PYTHON. I have an idea how to get image info when it is in our server. Buy no idea this can do with online resource image in PYTHON.

Finally done this as follow in python. Anyway have to download and get image info

```
import cStringIO
import urllib
import Image
file = urllib.urlopen('http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif')
im = cStringIO.StringIO(file.read())
img = Image.open(im)
print img.format, img.size, img.mode
GIF (120, 67) P
width, height = img.size
print width, height
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You must download a certain amount of the file before you get to the metadata that contains the dimensions of the image.

Comment: But in php we can do this as follow. why we can not do with python      <?php
$size = getimagesize("http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif");
var_dump($size);
?>

Comment: Above code giving fallowing result array(7) { [0]=> int(120) [1]=> int(67) [2]=> int(1) [3]=> string(23) "width="120" height="67"" ["bits"]=> int(7) ["channels"]=> int(3) ["mime"]=> string(9) "image/gif" }

Comment: Do you *really* believe that PHP doesn't download part of the file when doing that?!

Comment: I have no idea what is happening in side the "getimagesize()" php lib function in php. It is giving width and height?

Comment: If you don't understand what it's doing then why are you presenting it as an example?

Comment: But it is working example. That is why I presenting it. Try it out your self can see the result anyway. I jest asking is there any function like that in python also? That is all.

Comment: It downloads in PHP, therefore your comparison is invalid.

Comment: Usually the height and width parameters are embed in image header. The only drawback is that different file types have different headers. Basically you can write your own function which would read the header and stop downloading as soon as it gets the header.